# Representable $\text{Hom}$ functors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, descent, representable-functors

Let $X, Y, S$ be noetherian schemes, $X$ flat and quasi-projective over $S$, $Y$ projective over $S$.

- Is the hom-functor $T\mapsto\text{Hom}_T(X_T, Y_T)$ representable?

If $X$ is flat and *projective*, it is, by a standard graph argument to deduce representability from that of the Hilbert functor of $X\times_SY$.
If $X$ is *proper* and flat, then the hom-functor is an algebraic space.

- If so, is the representing object quasi-projective/projective?

Comment: No, that is not representable.  This is worked out explicitly in Claim 3.1 of the following article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602646.pdf  If the functor is representable for $Y$ projective, then for every Zariski open $U$ in $Y$, the functor is also representable with $Y$ replaced by $U$.  Now let $X$ and $Y$ both equal $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.  Then the Zariski tangent space of the functor at the identity morphism is a $k$-vector space of countably infinite dimension.  If the functor were representable, then the dimension would be either finite or uncountable.

Comment: @JasonStarr: A slightly more refined way to get a contradiction is to use Grothendieck's criterion for being locally of finite presentation (which also applies to algebraic spaces) to see that the tangent spaces have to be finite-dimensional in representable cases.